# Something's consuming my laptop's resources

Tags: windows-8.1, process

I bought my laptop 6 months ago. It's a Lenovo G50-70. Last week, my laptop got slow down so much that the cursor was lagging behind the motion of my mouse. It was obvious. Task manager took about 5 minutes to show up. It showed something shocking. There were 3 processes that were consuming the disk usage and the memory.

Today, the same *phenomena* happened again. I snapped it quite soon because the memory consuming process was increasing at a larger rate. It went to consuming about 6.5GB of the available 8GB RAM (even my games don't consume any more than 3GB of RAM), that I finally had to force-restart my laptop to do my works. Once restarted, things go fine.

I don't see any viruses in the system. And, I don't think it's a normal thing. Has anyone got any idea about this problem?

[image: ???!!!]